# Problem with FTP connections under Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp, ftp

Say I have an org-link like `[[file:/ftp:anonymous@ftp.gnu.org:]]` to an FTP site that I would like to open in `dired`. Unfortunately, when opening the link, the following is prompted:

> Opening FTP connection to ftp.gnu.org...
>
> tramp-file-name-handler: FTP Error: OPEN request failed:

Upon trying it a second time, Emacs tends to crash.

There is also a buffer `*ftp anonymous@ftp.gnu.org*` which has the following content (sorry, partly in German):

> Ung ltiger Hilfebefehl foo
>
> open ftp.gnu.org
>
> Verbindung mit ftp.gnu.org wurde hergestellt.
>
> 220 GNU FTP server ready.

Any idea what could be going on?
(I'm under Windows with Emacs 25.1.90.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) using `tramp` 2.2.13.25.2 as is.)

Comment: Please mention your Tramp version and your Emacs version.

Comment: There should be a buffer `*ftp anonymous@gnu.org*`. Do you see something there?

Comment: @Drew I've added version info.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus Yes, there is such a buffer! Sorry, I forgot to mention this. I've updated the question. Maybe `tramp` doesn't know how to properly use `ftp.exe`? In the PowerShell, `ftp.exe` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions given [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AngeFtp#toc9), I've downloaded an old windows port of [GNU ftp](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/emacs/windows/contrib/ftp-for-win32.zip) and then let `ange-ftp` know where it can find it:

```
(setq ange-ftp-ftp-program-name "c:/programs/ftp.exe")
```

Comment: I've corrected the link and it should be working now.